# What parts do I need in order to connect a light to my netduino?

Tags: arduino, components, light, netduino

I'm software engineer trying to get a little electronics project working. I have a netduino plus. I want to hook up a huge light [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0011CZV5A) and make it turn on and off. Where do I start? What would it take to make this happen? I'm not worried about the programming side I'm just curious what components I would need to get going. I'm a total noob so be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the supply voltage and current requirement?

Comment: That's a good question. How do I find that out?

Comment: Define "huge light", and no, not with some link.  Answering Leon's question would be a good start.

Comment: I included a link to the light. I just want something similar. Not sure if that device would actually work or not. Basically I want to have this police-light thing turn on anytime our build fails.

Comment: If you can't supply the necessary info the question should be closed.

Comment: I've provided the basics of what I'm trying to accomplish so how about at least pointing me in the right direction? If you were a total noob and trying to achieve what I've stated what parts would you buy and how would you approach it?

Comment: @Micah: The link adds nothing to the question because all it says that it's  1.7 pounds and it's $10.25. Do you want to make something like that yourself, or are you fine just buying the thing from Amazon then simply controlling the power to it?

Comment: I would be totally fine just using it and figuring out a way to control the power to it since that seems to be the easiest approach. Because of my lack of knowledge I realize I'm probably not giving enough information.

Comment: @Micah Is it a light that plugs into 120VAC? 12VDC? How much power does it need? 60W, 90W?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the manufacturer's site it says that it's AC operated, so you'll need a switch for that because the Netduino neither can stand the 120V nor can it supply the power needed.
Basically there are two ways to this: the **electromechanical relay** and the **triac**, which is an electronic switch to switch AC power.

**Relay**
The relay will still need more power than the Netduino will provide, so you'll need a transistor to provide the required current. The basic schematic is this:

[image]

The transistor will let a larger current flow through the relay's coil if a smaller current enters the base (the input from your Netduino). The 12V is the relay's rated coil voltage. Select an approriate relay if your Netduino's power supply gives a different voltage. The contacts need to be able to switch 120V AC, most probably at a relative low current. A 5A relay will do.
The transistor can be any small-signal NPN transistor, like the BC547. The diode can be a 1N4148.

**Triac**
This solution is all electronic, so no moving parts. It requires a few more parts than the relay.

[image]

The NAND gate on the left can be left out; it just shows that the MOC3041 is driven from a logic level.

**Which to choose**
Since you're new to electronics the second schematic may look even more daunting than the first one, so I would go for the relay to start with, though I like the triac solution better.

Comment: @Micah: Steven gives you the basics, look for an introduction to electronics for the details of how to use a transistor. That will also give you information on how to identify the pinout of parts.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. This is hugely helpful Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain a general approach. This has me pointed in the right direction. It's people like you who are willing to take the time for a total noob like me that makes the stackexchange community work!

Answer (score 5):

Micah, since you are new I will try and help you. First off: are you familiar with the [Netduino Forums](http://forums.netduino.com/)? That would be a great place to ask a Netduino related question like this.

Next Google is your friend; perhaps the reason you are getting a less than stellar welcome here is that spending a few minutes searching with Google will yield many possible solutions.

The basic issue you have here is that what you need to turn on and off draws more current and/or requires more voltage than the Netduino can safely handle. That is why you are being asked what voltage and current.

If you would like to switch a light that can be plugged into the 120 volt wall outlet, then this [power switch tail](https://www.adafruit.com/products/268) will work with your Netduino.

Hopefully you will take a greater interest in learning about electronics and the many other things your Netduino can do. By reading through the questions and answers here you can learn a lot that can help you.

Finally welcome to this website.

Comment: GIYF is not a proper answer. It can be applied to most questions here, and stackexchange might as well close.

Comment: stevenvh: I would agree with your comment if that was the only information provided in the answer. I believe you will agree that I did not stop there but went on to provide a specific solution that met the requirements.